# Get nested json with a list of unflattened jsons?

Tags: java, json, deserialization, nested-loops

Test case 1:

input

```
[{"key1": {"valueA": "", "valueB": ""}},
{"key2": {"valueC": "key3"}},
{"key3": {"valueD": "", "valueE": ""}}]
```

output

```
[{"key1": {"valueA": "", "valueB": ""}},
{"key2": {"valueC": {"valueD": "", "valueE": ""}}]
```

Test case 2:

input

```
[{"key1": {"valueA": "key2"}},
{"key2": {"valueB": "key3"}},
{"key3": {"valueC": "", "valueD": ""}}]
```

output

```
[{"key1": {"valueA": {"valueB": {"valueC": "", "valueD": ""}}}}]
```

Constraints

- All values should either be an empty string or an object.
- Depth 1 json object(`{"key1": ...}`, `{"key2": ...}`, ...) should have only one key-value element.
- The task can take recursively, which means traverse should not be limited to certain level.

I'm struggling with this problem for a week... Please help me to solve it or name java library so that I can take a look at the source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an algorithm and an implementation.

### Algorithm

1. Get all keys that correspond to a Map value (not to a String), put them in `objectMap`.
2. Fill `rootKeys` with keys from `objectMap`. These would be top-level keys in the resulting map.
3. Recursively traverse `objectMap` maps, replace non-empty string values (e.g. in `"valueC": key3"`, `"key3"` gets replaced). If a key is replaced, remove it from `rootKeys`.
4. Serialize `rootKeys` (with corresponding values).

### Implementation

Constraint: input json should be a list.

```java
import com.google.gson.Gson;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

class RecursiveJsonFlattener {
    private final Map<String, Map<String, Object>> objectMap = new HashMap<>();
    private final Set<String> rootKeys = new HashSet<>();
    private final Object[] jsonData;
    private final Gson serializer = new Gson();

    public RecursiveJsonFlattener(String jsonData) {
        this.jsonData = serializer.fromJson(jsonData, Object[].class);
    }

    public String getFlattened() {
        for (var obj : jsonData) {
            if (obj instanceof Map) {
                addToKeys((Map<String, Object>) obj);
            }
        }
        rootKeys.addAll(objectMap.keySet());

        for (var map : objectMap.values()) {
            substituteStringValues(map);
        }

        var resultingMap = rootKeys.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(key -> key, objectMap::get));
        return serializer.toJson(resultingMap);
    }

    private void addToKeys(Map<String, Object> map) {
        for (var entry : map.entrySet()) {
            if (!(entry.getValue() instanceof String)) {
                objectMap.put(entry.getKey(), (Map<String, Object>) entry.getValue());
                addToKeys((Map<String, Object>) entry.getValue());
            }
        }
    }

    private void substituteStringValues(Map<String, Object> map) {
        for (var entry : map.entrySet()) {
            var value = entry.getValue();
            if (value instanceof String && !value.equals("")) {
                map.put(entry.getKey(), objectMap.get(value));
                rootKeys.remove(value);
            } else if (entry.getValue() instanceof Map) {
                substituteStringValues((Map<String, Object>) value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String jsonString = "[{\"key1\": {\"valueA\": \"\", \"valueB\": \"\"}},\n" +
                "{\"key2\": {\"valueC\": \"key3\"}},\n" +
                "{\"key3\": {\"valueD\": \"\", \"valueE\": \"\"}}]";
        System.out.println(new RecursiveJsonFlattener(jsonString).getFlattened());
        // prints {"key1":{"valueA":"","valueB":""},"key2":{"valueC":{"valueD":"","valueE":""}}}
    }
}
```

I use Gson library, add dependency via Gradle: `implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.10.1'` or via Maven:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.1</version>
</dependency>
```